# What is the use of msg.sender in solidity?

Tags: mapping, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ether

In this codpiece, I am finding it hard to figure out what is `msg.sender` is and how it works internally.

What I am understanding is, we have a mapping favoriteNumber, and the key is an address and the value is a uint.

What is the meaning of comment - "Update our `favoriteNumber` mapping to store `_myNumber` under `msg.sender`, I am understanding that we are updating favoriteNumber, but what does it mean that under msg.sender. What is the role of this method, how it's working?

```
    mapping (address => uint) favoriteNumber;

function setMyNumber(uint _myNumber) public {
  // Update our `favoriteNumber` mapping to store `_myNumber` under `msg.sender`
  favoriteNumber[msg.sender] = _myNumber;
  // ^ The syntax for storing data in a mapping is just like with arrays
}

function whatIsMyNumber() public view returns (uint) {
  // Retrieve the value stored in the sender's address
  // Will be `0` if the sender hasn't called `setMyNumber` yet
  return favoriteNumber[msg.sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every smart contract invocation has a caller address. Each EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine that executes the code) knows which
account carries out each action. In Solidity, you can access the calling account by
referencing `msg.sender`

So when you call a function of solidity contract, your contract already gets the information of your account, so your account is the `msg.sender`

`favoriteNumber` is a mapping. think it like a javascript object. It maps the account addresses to their favourite number.

```
 0x9C6520Dd9F8d0af1DA494C37b64D4Cea9A65243C -> 10
```

So when you call `setMyNumber(_myNumber)`, you are passing your favourite number. so this number will be stored in `favoriteNumber` mapping like this:

```
 yourAccountAdress -> yourFavouriteNumber
```

So when you call `whatIsMyNumber` function, since EVM already gets your account number, checks in the mappings and returns you your favourite number.

Answer (score 0):

In solidity exists 3 types of variables: state, local and global.
example of global variables:

- msg.sender (sender of the message)
- msg.value (number of wei sent with the message)

pseudocode from `favoriteNumber[msg.sender] = _myNumber;`

> - given a favoriteNumber list,
> - select the address of the account calling this function,
> - assign _myNumber to that address

note: global variables are available in all contracts by default. see more info here: [solidity docs - global variable](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg)