# UseDapp - useCall - How to get return value from Solidity function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am still quite new with react and solidity and don't know where to start.
I can update a String and want to print it out after I changed it.
But I want the String from the Blockchain.
The return value is still 'undefined'.

My index.ts file:

```
export function MyString(contract: Contract) {
    const { state, send } = useContractFunction(contract, "setString", {});
    return { state, send };
}

export function GetMyString(contract: Contract) {
    const { value, error } = useCall({
        contract: contract,
        method: 'getString',
        args: []
    }) ?? {};

    if (error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error.message);
        return undefined;
    }
    console.log("value", value);
    return value;
}
```

My react component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useEthers } from "@usedapp/core";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import myStringContractAbi from "./abi/myString.json";
import { myStringContractAddress } from "./contracts";
import { Contract } from "@ethersproject/contracts";

import { MyString, GetMyString } from "./hooks"

function App() {

  const { activateBrowserWallet, account, deactivate } = useEthers();

  const simpleContractInterface = new ethers.utils.Interface(myStringContractAbi);
  const contract = new Contract(myStringContractAddress, simpleContractInterface, ethers.getDefaultProvider(42));

  const { send, state } = MyString(contract);

  const value = GetMyString(contract);

  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("")
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newText = event.target.value === "" ? "" : String(event.target.value)
    setText(newText)
  }

  const sendString = async () => {
     send(text);
  }

  const getContractString = async () => {
    console.log("APP VALUE", value);
    alert(value);
  }


  React.useEffect(() => {
    state.status === 'Exception' && console.log('State of set String: ', state.errorMessage);

    state.status === 'Success' && console.log('Set String successfully!');
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {!account && <button onClick={() => activateBrowserWallet()}> Connect </button>}
      {account && (
        <div>
          <button onClick={deactivate}>Disconnect</button>
        </div>
      )}
       <div>
          {account ? (
            <div>My Account Address: {account} </div>
          ) : (
            <div>Kein Account verbunden!</div>
          )}
        </div>

        <input onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={sendString}>Call Function</button>

        <button onClick={getContractString}>Call Get String Function</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyString {
    string public myString;

    constructor() {
        myString = "Not set yet";
    }

    function setString(string memory _myString) public {
        myString = _myString;
    }

    function getString() public view returns (string memory) {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me? Do you need other info?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get any value, you can not use `useContractFunction`. Use `useCall` instead of thats or use `ethers` library.

Example `useCall`

```js
import { useCall } from '@usedapp/core';
import { Contract } from '@ethersproject/contracts'; // comes with `@usedapp/core`
import {utils} from 'ethers';

const CONTRACT_ADDR = "0xa513E6E4b8f2a923D98304ec87F64353C4D5C853";
const Interface = new utils.Interface(ABI); // ABI is array
const ContractInstance = new Contract(CONTRACT_ADDR, Interface);

// Custom contract payable function

const useTokenBalance = () => {
  const { value, error } = useCall({
    contract: ContractInstance,
    method: 'TokenBalance',
    args: [] /* params */
  });

  if(error) {
    return undefined
  }
  console.log("value", value);
  return value;
};

function App() {
  //...
  const TokenBalance  = useTokenBalance();

  const getTokenBalance = async () => {
   alert(TokenBalance);
  }
}
```

API Documentation: https://usedapp-docs.netlify.app/docs/api%20reference/hooks/#usecall

See tests: https://github.com/TrueFiEng/useDApp/blob/17b80218e803395a16a29b94ef0b1b24931f50fb/packages/core/src/hooks/useCall.test.tsx

How to use `ethers` library in `useDApp` hook framework;

```js
import { useEthers } from '@usedapp/core';
import { Contract as CTR } from 'ethers';

const CONTRACT_ADDR = "0xa513E6E4b8f2a923D98304ec87F64353C4D5C853";

function App() {
  //...
  const { account, library } = useEthers();

  const getTokenBalance = async () => {
    const signer = library.getSigner();
    const ctr = new CTR(CONTRACT_ADDR, ABI, signer);
    let tx = await ctr.TokenBalance(/* params */);
    alet(tx);
  }
}
```

API Documentation: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract--creating

Tested versions;

- `^5.6.5` ethers
- `^1.0.2` @usedapp/core

## **Update**

Fully source code;

```
import './App.css';
import { useEthers, useContractFunction, useCall } from '@usedapp/core';
import {useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {utils, constants, BigNumber, Contract as CTR} from 'ethers';
import { Contract } from '@ethersproject/contracts'

const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:4000";
const CONTRACT_ADDR = "0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9";

const ABI = require('./Post.json').abi;
const Interface = new utils.Interface(ABI);
const Instance = new Contract(CONTRACT_ADDR, Interface);

const useAddMessage = () => {
  const { state, send, event } = useContractFunction(
    Instance,
    'addMessage',
    {}
  );
  return { state, send, event };
};

function App() {
  const { state: addMessageState, send: addMessage } = useAddMessage();

  const { activateBrowserWallet, account, library, chainId } = useEthers();

  const [ownerBalance, set_ownerBalance] = useState(0);
  const [contractInstance, set_contractInstance] = useState(null);

  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  const [chainMsgs, setChainMsgs] = useState([]);

  // Error watching
  useEffect(() => {
    addMessageState.status === 'Exception' &&
      console.log('addMessageState: ', addMessageState.errorMessage);

    addMessageState.status === 'Success' &&
      console.log('Successfully added message to chain');
  }, [addMessageState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(account){

      library.getBalance(account).then(balance => {
        set_ownerBalance(utils.formatUnits(balance, "ether"));
      });

      set_contractInstance(new CTR(CONTRACT_ADDR, ABI, library.getSigner()));
    }
  }, [account]);
  
  const addMsg = async () => {
    if(msg.length > 0){
      let addedMessage = await addMessage(msg);
      // when below function correctly worked, that triggered `Error watching` statement
    }
  };

  const getMsg = async () => {
    let chainMessages = await contractInstance.getMessages({from: account});
    setChainMsgs(chainMessages);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <header>
        {
          !account &&
          <button onClick={() => activateBrowserWallet()} >Connect Wallet</button>
        }

        {
          account &&
          <>
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
              <h1 id="msg-addr">{ellipseAddress(account, 5)}</h1>
              <span style={{margin: '0 0.5rem'}}>{ownerBalance} ETH</span>
            </div>
            <br />
          </>
        }
      </header>

      <main>
        {
          account &&
          <>
            <section>
              <input type={"text"} placeholder={"Leave trail"} value={msg} onChange={e => setMsg(e.target.value)} />
              <button onClick={async () => await addMsg()}>Add Message</button>
            </section>
            <section>
              <button onClick={async () => await getMsg()}>Get Message</button>
              {
                chainMsgs.length > 0 &&
                <ul>
                  {chainMsgs.map((chainMsg, i) => {
                    return (
                      <li key={i}>{chainMsg}</li>
                    )
                  })}
                </ul>
              }
              
            </section>
          </>
        }
        
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

function ellipseAddress(address='', width=10) {
  return !address ? '' : address.slice(0, width) + "..."  + address.slice(-width);
}

export default App;
```

[image: output]

Check correctly package version from `package.json`;

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@usedapp/core": "^1.0.2",
    "ethers": "^5.6.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the end of useCall I had to add this:  ?? {};
I get now: undefined. I can update my question at the top, that you know what I did.
In your answer I dont understand the 'error watching' part. Where do you get the TokenBalanceState ?

Comment: @LucaF sorry for missing explaning and code.I wrote according to your contract code, full example with screen output. With both instance and useContractFunction example. I hope, It might be helpful.

Comment: I am really thankful for your time but I dont get it. I changed the useCall function similar to your example. I am using now an easier example. I have only a String, a function to set and a function to get it. But if I want to get it, I only get undefined. Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because the `account` that you are passing to `getMessages(String(account))` is not same type as `address` type in solidity.

In fact, to store the sender's address, you do not have to pass the account as function parameter. Etherum EVM already detect the caller address as `msg.sender`.

[What is msg.sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799103/what-is-the-use-of-msg-sender-in-solidity/70799295#70799295)

IN solidity:

```
function getMessages() public view returns (string[] memory)
    {
        return messages[msg.sender];
    }
```

in react side just call the function without passing a parameter.

```
const handleLoad = () => {
        getMessages()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful but I still get the error and the messages dont show up. The error repeats after a period of time and always 113 times. I update my code really quick.

Comment: Can you check return value of  useContractFunction(postContract, 'addMessage', {transactionName: "Call 'Post' function!"}). something is failing here. Also call getMessages inside try/catch

Comment: What is the error of addMessage? Its working for me. I can see the send text on: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xcea85f8f5ff0692cb98d794ae4a29e319ca2a3bca553b32b279a9c127a25677c -> click to see more -> view input as. But I go for the try catch in getMessage and tell you whats happening

Comment: @Luca, I meant  this :  useContractFunction(postContract, 'getMessages', {transactionName: "Call 'getMessages' function!"})

Comment: I get 'invalid hash' and when I log it -> 
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined 
But I dont get it. Why is it so complicated, just get a String Array and print it? Thats all I want.

Comment: can u set up metamask in different browser and run your code in that browser. I had an issue today with chrome-browser, I used firefox and my project worked

Comment: ok I dont get the errors in firefox now. Still doesnt show anything. In which variable is the Array? getMessages, right?

Comment: Now check the status of hash. Is it undefined or there is a value

Comment: Firefox is a very good tipp. Chrome has problems with status messages as well. 

send Message works. This is the status (state): Object { receipt: {…}, transaction: {…}, status: "Success", chainId: 42 }

get Message doesnt work: Object { status: "Exception", errorMessage: "missing argument: passed to contract", chainId: 42 }. The return of the contract function is: 
Promise { <state>: "pending" }

Comment: Ok I'm clueless. When I use different browser, I get different errors. Now I changed from Kovan to Rinkeby, I get new errors...
Object { status: "Exception", errorMessage: "call revert exception (method=\"getMessages()\", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)", chainId: 4 }

Comment: Since we have been fighting for a while, send me the github repo. I will take a look

Comment: https://github.com/Luca-Fischer/test.git

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to see about promises in js, but long history short to see the return value you should wait for it this can be done this way `const {state, send} = await useContractFunction(...)`, but in order to use the await keyword the function where you use it should have the keyword async `async (postContract: Contract) =>`, remember that all read and writes to the blockchain uses promises

Comment: Thanks, but 'await has no effect on the type of this expression' when I put it infront of useContractFunction. And with only asnyc I get the problem in the react part: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ send: (...args: any[]) => Promise<void>; state: TransactionStatus; }>'. Adding es2018 in tsconfig doenst fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that same error when missing `await` keyword, we should always define it like that so the code waits for the smart contract function execution. I suggest you to add `await` before calling your smart contract function.

Comment: It says: 'await has no effect on the type of this expression' when I put it infront of useContractFunction.